# "if (object is (string, Color))" c# 7.0 tuple usage doesn't work

Tags: c#, tuples, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC and I have installed the `System.ValueTuple` package which enables the new c# 7.0 tuple usage, but I can't make it work in this specific case:

[image]

As you can see, the first method doesn't have any red squigglies and it just works. But trying to do `o is (string, Color)` fails with unrelated errors:

[image]

Can the new tuples not be used in this way? Or is it just the current state of the package? I have updated it to the latest version btw, which is 4.3.0 at this time. I've read [this MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) but didn't find any such usage.

Comment: The nuget package only supplies the types necessary, it doesn't supply the part of the compiler that handles this so while the Nuget package is necessary to use tuples, it has no bearing on the error message you're getting.

Comment: For future reference it would be better if you post code and error messages as text, and not as screenshots, makes it easier for others, like me, to experiment with the code and analyze the results.

Comment: Out of curiousity: does "o is Tuple<string, Color>" work?

Comment: @Dyrborg It will compile but mean something else since the new tuples are type `ValueTuple<...>`, not `Tuple<...>`. Having said that, doing `o is ValueTuple<string, Color>` *will* work and returns `true`.

Comment: Also note that the if-statement has nothing to do with this, it is solely this expression that for some reason is illegal: `o is (string, Color)`.

Comment: Yes, I know. It could have been `bool b = o is (string, Color)` and it would not work just the same.

Answer (score 10):

[Roslyn contains tests that ensure using tuples in pattern matching *does* cause errors](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/8f06266/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/Emit/CodeGen/CodeGenTupleTest.cs#L13238) (added in [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/11012), which does not explain anything), so it seems this is currently the expected behavior. I'm not sure what is the reason for that, or if the final version of C# 7.0 is planned to behave like this. It certainly is something that I would expect to work.

Answer (score 7):

Some pattern matching features were removed from the C# 7 release. This includes pattern matching for tuples. This is pulled out and put into future branches. (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10866)

> This means that the more advanced kinds of pattern matching, explained effectively by reddit poster wreckedadvent, will not be available in C# 7, including:
>
> - recursive pattern forms such as positional patterns (e.g., p is Person("Mickey", *), property patterns (e.g., p is Person {FirstName is "Mickey"}), tuple patterns, wildcard *, etc.

Source: https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/05/csharp7-pattern-matching-removed

**UPDATE:** The type test `(int, int)` can be interpreted as a tuple pattern. For example if you want to do a type test and bind the outcome to a variable. So type testing is involved in tuple patterns. For example `(int x, int y)` can be a type test or a tuple pattern. See the pattern-matching discussion at github: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11744

Comment: I don't understand why the pattern matching removal also removed certain cases of `o is Type` where `Type` in this case is a tuple. It looks like the compiler tries really hard to gloss over the fact that `(T1, T2)` really is just `ValueType<T1, T2>` and in some cases some attributes to fake member names, and then in the case of the `is` operator the support is just taken out. Then again, I haven't read far into the C# 7 documentation or the implementation but it seems odd to me that this particular part is tied to the more advanced pattern matching.

Comment: In particular because `o is ValueType<string, Color>` **does** work.

Comment: I don't know the implementation specifics but I think you're talking about pattern matching with the asterisk symbol, and it seems like a separate feature which should have no effect on this more common feature.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the reason why this tied to (advanced) pattern matching is also for me unknown. Because this looks like a common feature as user1306322 describes. This is what i found in the PR describing this case: `This one is a little worrying. It suggests that (1, 2) is being parsed as a tuple expression, which should not be possible in this context. But that will have to be sorted out later when we parse tuple patterns.`

Comment: @user1306322 did some digging in the design meetings of tuples and updated the answer.